# Set parameter into translation by annotation (Symfony)

Tags: symfony, annotations, translation

How to set parameter into translation by annotation?

**Entity**:

```
   /**
     * @var
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 5,
     *      max = 5,
     *      minMessage = "userRegister.token.min_length", //set min?
     *      maxMessage = "userRegister.token.max_length"  //set max?
     * )
     */
    protected $smsToken;
```

**validators.ru.yml**:

```
userRegister:
  token:
    min_length: "Ваш токен sms должен быть не менее %min% символов"
    max_length: "Ваш токен sms не может быть длиннее %max% символов"
```

Comment: try with `%limit%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything turned out to be easier than I thought:

```
userRegister:
  token:
    min_length: "Ваш токен sms должен быть не менее {{ limit }} символов"
    max_length: "Ваш токен sms не может быть длиннее {{ limit }} символов"
```